# how popup phone keyboard when user taps on browser screen in an iPhone like device?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I have a canvas element on a web page. When the user taps on the canvas element in the safari browser I want to popup the iPhone text entry keyboard. Then javascript code will display the text entered on the canvas. How to do this?